# Form submit button not working in Firefox

Tags: html, forms, firefox, form-submit

I am stumped. I have a form button like this: `<input type="submit" value="Send" name="sdForm-submit">` Very basic, right?

It works perfectly fine, except in Firefox. In Firefox, when clicked, nothing happens. The form is not submitted. It's not submitting with jQuery or anything, just a plain old html form with an action.

The weirdest part is that if I right click and click "inspect element" in Firefox, and then click on the button (as if to select it for inspecting) the form submits! Which is also wrong, because inspecting the element shouldn't activate it.

I'm really confused what might be happening. Any insight appreciated if someone might know what's happening.

Edit:
This is the snippet of code the displays the submit button:

```
$output .= '<input type="submit" name="sdForm-submit" value="'.$submitValue.'" />';
```

The full code (a plugin) which builds the form, is here: http://pastebin.com/3y3KEp94

It's just PHP and html creating the form based on various options settings set by the user.

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: Post edited with link to full code

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more details about your script. Try with event.preventDefault() , if this does not work, please edit your question with more details.